# groovy sort list using part of list element

Tags: groovy

I've got a list that looks like this:

```
C:\basedir\2011_April\data_20110407.csv
...
C:\basedir\2011_January\data_20110101.csv
```

The second file comes later in the list, because "January" is after "April".  I need this list to instead be sorted by the file date, i.e. the data_20110101.csv file should come before the data_20110407.csv file (keeping the whole directory path).  Can someone give me an example that can sort on subfields like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the sort method on the list and pass a closure that extracts the date from each string as the sort criteria:

```
fileList.sort { 
  def matcher = it =~ /(\d{8})\.csv/
  matcher[0][1] 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christoph, am still digesting the syntax as I try it, but got an error:  Class java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
Message: index is out of range 0..-1 (index = 0)

      println fileList
      fileList.sort {
         def matcher = it =~ /(\d{8})\.csv/
         matcher[0][1]
       }

Comment: All that gobly gook StackOverflow put into one line is exactly your syntax, i.e. separated in lines.

Comment: Well, it seems that at least one element in the list doesn't match the regex pattern (8 digits followed by ".csv"). If that is the case, you run into a IndexOutOfBoundsException. You can check before accessing the matched group, `if (matcher.length > 0)` but you need an alternative sorting criteria in case the input String doesn't have a date substring.

Comment: I see, thanks for that.  Can you tell me the significance of including the matcher[0][1] inside?  I tried removing it with using an example of "correct elements", and it still worked.

Comment: matcher[0] will give you the first match for the given pattern. matcher[0][0] would give you the complete string that matched the pattern. matcher[0][1] will give you just the matched regex group part, which is defined by the parentheses in the pattern, i.e. the 8 digits only.

Comment: Got it.  Don't know why leaving "matcher[0][1]" out would work -- just using the Groovy console with my simple two liner above, but it does.  In my real example/code, it doesn't